# Magento on EC2 Very slow

Tags: magento, amazon-ec2

I need a little help in optimizing the Magento Site on EC2 instance. Kindly see this store: 
www.entertainmentstore.in

Server configuration is:

```
t1.medium
Magento 1.9.1
```

We are using Route 53 for DNS settings.

We want to keep the costs low, as we don't anticipate having a lot of visitors in the short term. But none the less, the site seems painstakingly slow. Kindly suggest how we can optimize it further.

Really new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with optimizing your DB, make sure the InnoDB engine is optimized. Make sure you have a PHP opcode caching setup. APC if you have PHP 5.3

Comment: Thank you, APC did make the site faster. How can I optimize the InnoDB engine?

Comment: By default InnoDB is not even an option. So make sure the basics are covered and that you are setting enough RAM buffer size for InnoDB. I find 300MB to be the base minimum for Magento sites. Also make sure you set the transactions commit to only occur once per second at best.